# Help with booting

Tags: 13.04

I just uninstalled Ubuntu and erased all the partitions but when I boot my computer all I get is this:

Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first.           word, <kbd>TAB</kbd> lists possible command completions. Anywhere else <kbd>TAB</kbd> lists possible device or file completions.

```
GRUB>
```

How can I fix this so I can boot into windows?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you've deleted your configuration which requires a rescue disc (windows or live cd)

To boot to windows type the following (change it to match your system, type ls to list partitions) :

1. root(hd0,0)
2. makeactive
3. chainloader + 1 (or chainloader --force + 1)
4. boot

For more details, check :

- http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/booting-windows-from-the-grub-prompt-275446/
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71555/boot-windows-from-grub-rescue-command-prompt

Answer (score 0):

As stated by yilmi, this will require a **Live CD or reinstall**.

Since it is based on Ubuntu I'll recommend '[Boot Repair Disk](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/)'.
This tool has helped me numerous times, especially with EFI BIOS issues and dual-booting.
It's normally available from the `ppa:yannubuntu` repository.

Please **stay away** from the advanced options if you're not comfortable with some heavy tinkering. The recommended options will usually patch your issues.

**Further documentation** for this tool can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).